# How to properly escape C# string for use in MySQL"where Like "

Tags: c#, mysql, string

I have been tasked with searching a MySQL database using a "where like" in a stored procedure. My where clause is being passed as a parameter to MySQL.

QA has created a customer named "Fak'n & " account/\home". Using a shorter string up to the slash works fine. As soon as the backslash is used in the search it does not work.

I have escaped the single quote without issue.

I have successfully escaped everything but the "\".
In debug in VS2012 I see my string variable as `"Fak'n & \" account/\\home"` At this point I have not yet dealt with the single quote. Also C# has done a bit of escaping already.

Experimenting I have found that I need 5 backslashes for MySQL to be happy with it in the like statement. I can't seem to make C# accept an odd number of slashes.

```
string name1 = name.Replace(@"\", @"\\"); yields "Fak'n & \" account/\\\\home"
```

I tried every variation I could think of in the replace function. I even manually inserted a single backslash but is was auto escaped and then I had 6 backslashes. Here is the function as I stopped with it.

```
        public DataTable findAllLookup(string name, int sortOrder = 1)
        {
            string whereVal = "";
            if (name.Length > 0)
            {
                //Don't let apostrophy's through you
               string name1 = name.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
               string name2 = name1.Replace("'", @"\'");
                whereVal = whereVal + " and CustNam like '%" + name2 + "%'";
            }

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            conn.Open();

            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("sp_a1cust_list_lookup_custom", conn);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("pmCompany", Company));
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("pmWhereVal", whereVal));
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("pmSort", sortOrder));

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "a1cust");
            dt = ds.Tables["a1cust"];

            return dt;
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the string in the debugger will give you an escaped version. I suggest you print the value out. Also, are you using parameterized SQL? You really, really should be - but it's not clear from the question.

Comment: Jon Skeet,  Yes I am, just part of the where clause is passed as a parameter. The proc is a little strange.